# Custom Object to replace tasks to handle 255 Char limit

Tags: custom-object, tasks, standard-objects, activities

In salesforce lightning, The Task/Activities Object (I believe one inherits from another), seems to have a hard limit of 255 chars for a field and does not have options for the text field long or rich options.

Therefore, it seems the option is to make a custom object to emulate the activities.

I was looking through the docs to see if their were any "gotchas" I will run into or would have to plan for, such as special relationships or triggers that the task would have which I would need to emulate.

Could someone a) Point me in the right direction docs-wise or let me know what if any special attributes of task/activities are or b) Let me know if there is some other work around for the 255 char limit...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's a limitation as of now. If you're using industry clouds (such as Health Cloud), I would urge you not to create a custom object entirely. The reason is that Tasks are an integral part of a whole bunch of built-in automation and various aspects of the core data model. For example, Care Plan Template will include Tasks. There are certain scenarios where Tasks get automatically created by the system

Coming to workarounds, it all depends on your context. Consider the below options and you can probably customize it for your need

1. Add the Rich Text Area component to the lightning page if it's going
   to be static text for all records.
2. Add Notes in Task layout. You can provide instructions to the user
   to fill this. You can create a whole bunch of automation using Flow
   around this based on the subject.
3. Create a custom object with this text field and create a lookup
   relationship instead of creating entirely a new object. You can use
   custom lwc or visualforce componenets to display this field if you
   don't want them to be displayed as related list

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Much appreciated. The healthcloud or industry clouds isn't an issue per se, but you hit my concern on the nail. 
1. Unfortunate, but not going to work. 2. The tasks are being created from an external automated source, so 3. seems the best option. It will mean a little more complex on the JSforce calls being made, but ce est la vie. Give me some time and I'll implement and answer appropriately shortly...